# Accessing HDFS web UI from another machine

Tags: windows, hdfs, webui

I can access my Hadoop File System from Web UI `<IP address>:50070` . I want to access the same from a machine present outside of cluster. I tried to do it but it says `webpage not found` error. How can I access my HDFS from windows machine through a URL?